# Search records by DATE in NSTableView and CoreData using InterfaceBuilder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, predicate, nssearchfield

I have an NSTableView which pull data from CoreData using ArrayController. In my form, I also have search field.

Search form works just fine if:

1. I select the search field, and in binding inspector under predicate I bind the search field to the array controller that is used to get the data in the nstableview.
2. In the predicate format field I add

   customerName contains[cd] $value or customerWebsite contains[cd] $value

So now either I search for customerName (STRING) or customerWebsite (STRING), I get the results just fine.

But, If i change the field with the field which contains DATE, my search doesn't work. For example noting of bellow doesn't work:

```
contractExpiresOn contains[cd] $value
contractExpiresOn == $value
contractExpiresOn = $value
contractExpiresOn >= $value
contractExpiresOn > $value
contractExpiresOn %LIKE $value
//contractExpiresOn is DATE
```

When I search using the above predicate formats, the app doesn't crash, but no results are returned, even for example I have dates that start with 0, as soon as I type 0 in the search field, NSTableView is empty.

Can anyone tell me how can I make my search to work with dates trough interface builder, or if that is not possible, how can I do that programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare a date with a string and you have to do some programming. Create a category on NSDate and add a method for converting the date to a string.
For example:

```
@implementation NSDate(Search)

static NSDateFormatter *searchDateFormatter = nil;

- (NSString *)searchString {
    if (!searchDateFormatter) {
        searchDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        searchDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        searchDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    }
    return [searchDateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}

@end
```

The predicate format is `birthday.searchString contains $value`.

Comment: Works like a charm....but could this be done just adding this function in my m file instead of using category? Not that it bothers me to use category, just trying to learn few things....@Willeke

Comment: The category extends the functionality of NSDate. When you add the method to your .m file it would be addded to your class instead of NSDate.